# Reemplazar corchetes en consulta

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tento esta consulta:

```
select 
f.contrato_serv_nro,
array_agg(f.client_nro)  as firmas
from firmantes as f
group by f.contrato_serv_nro
```

el cual da el resultado de:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que el resultado de firmas sean reemplazados por corchetes.

Algo de Contexto:
Tengo esta grilla y su función sería que al hacer clic en algunos de los datos que refleja, automáticamente cargue en cabecera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como pueden apreciar en la imagen de abajo, no carga en el lbl multiselect "firma(s)"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo el log:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen de arriba, la fila "contrato_serv_firm" trae los datos {3,4}, no sé si esto difiere en algo.

```js
function listar() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "controlador.php"
  }).done(function(resultado) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultado));
    var lineas = "";
    for (rs of resultado) {
      lineas += "<tr onclick='seleccion(" + JSON.stringify(rs) + ")'>"
      lineas += "<td>";
      lineas += rs.contrato_serv_nro;
      lineas += "</td>";
      lineas += "<td>";
      lineas += rs.cliente;
      lineas += "</td>";
      lineas += "<td>";
      lineas += rs.unidad;
      lineas += "</td>";
      lineas += "<td>";
      lineas += rs.contrato_serv_estado;
      lineas += "</td>";
      lineas += "</tr>"
    }
    $("#grilla_datos").html(lineas);
    formatoTabla();
  }).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    alert(c);
  })
}

function seleccion(json) {
  Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
    $("#" + key).val(json[key]);
  });
  $(".editable").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".form-line").attr("class", "form-line focused");
  listarDetalles();
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right"> Firma(s): </label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select multiple="" name="contrato_serv_firm" id="contrato_serv_firm" class="chosen-select form-control editable" data-placeholder="Agregar Firmantes...">
      <option value="0"> </option>
      <?php
                                                        $sql = "SELECT client_nro, client_nomb_comercial FROM cliente where client_estado='ACTIVO' order by client_nomb_comercial asc";
                                                        $resultado = pg_query($conexion, $sql);
 while ($datos = pg_fetch_array($resultado)) {
      ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $datos['client_nro'] ?>">
          <?php echo $datos['client_nomb_comercial'] ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }?>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Unidad</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="grilla_datos">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Luego, primero, por favor agrega la etiqueta del motor que usas, y luego no me queda claro que quiere decir _"que el resultado de firmas sean reemplazados por corchetes"_, creo que vendría bien que des un ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener como resultado, dejando el resultado actual que obtienes.

Comment: Puedes especificar por qué necesitas obtener {3,4} en vez de (3,4), ¿no te sirve un replace en tu front? Se agradecería un poco más de contexto compañero

Comment: Allí agregue un poco del contexto.

Answer (score 0):

La función [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-GROUPING-TABLE) entrega un array y la forma en que postgresql representa un array es justamente con las llaves. Para resolver lo que buscas, debes convertir este array en una cadena mediante [`array_to_string()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), especificando la cadena que quieres como separador. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       array_to_string(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ', ');
```

| array | array_to_string |
| --- | --- |
| {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 |

Comment: Me funcionó con el método que me has dicho. Aprovechando, se puede agrupar en uno solo el resultado de array_to_string? group by no me funciona ya que la tabla cliente tiene diferentes id y me duplica los resultados. Muchas gracias

Comment: Agregue un poco de contexto, para que tenga una idea de lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Tú estás pidiendo un arreglo al motor y eso es lo que te devuelve, cuando lo que quieres es una lista separada por comas, que es básicamente una cadena de texto. Para ello existe la función [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select   f.contrato_serv_nro
       , string_agg(f.client_nro, ',')  as firmas
  from firmantes as f
 group by f.contrato_serv_nro
```

Te devolverá lo que buscas.